# Referencing a table twice in rails/postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am using PostgreSQL as my db in rails. I have a User model and a Product model. I am trying to make a Transaction model where I want to reference user twice, once as buyer and once as seller. I generated the models as suggested in this post (answer by toasterlovin)
[Write a migration with reference to a model twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880340/write-a-migration-with-reference-to-a-model-twice)
However it gives me an error when I use PostgreSQL (with SQLite it worked fine). I get the following error. What can I do to resolve this?

> {StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "buyers" does not exist
>   : ALTER TABLE "transactions" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_0b24a7fcc3"
>   FOREIGN KEY ("buyer_id")
>     REFERENCES "buyers" ("id")
>   C:/Users/Powerhouse/Desktop/CodingDojo/ruby/rails/demo/db/migrate/20161024032156_create_transactions.rb:3:in `change'
>
>   C:in`migrate'
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "buyers" does not exist
>   : ALTER TABLE "transactions" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_0b24a7fcc3"
>   FOREIGN KEY ("buyer_id")
>     REFERENCES "buyers" ("id")
>   C:/Users/Powerhouse/Desktop/CodingDojo/ruby/rails/demo/db/migrate/20161024032156_create_transactions.rb:3:in `change'
>
>   C:in`migrate'
>   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "buyers" does not exist
>   C:/Users/Powerhouse/Desktop/CodingDojo/ruby/rails/demo/db/migrate/20161024032156_create_transactions.rb:3:in `change'
>
>   C:in`migrate'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)  }

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
    has_many :sales,  :class_name => 'Transaction', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
    has_many :purchases,  :class_name => 'Transaction', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Transaction model

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Migration files

User

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Product

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Transaction

```
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.references :buyer, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :seller, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :product, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: please paste your models.

Comment: code for Models and Migration added @Sravan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `PostgreSql` not understanding how to make the custom association foreign keys.

Try changing the migration file to,

```
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.integer :buyer_id
      t.integer :seller_id
      t.integer :product_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index(:transactions, :buyer_id)
    add_index(:transactions, :seller_id)
    add_index(:transactions, :product_id)
    add_foreign_key :transactions, :users, column: :buyer_id
    add_foreign_key :transactions, :users, column: :seller_id
  end
end
```

It automatically links `buyer_id` to `user`, taking the power of

`belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User'`

The above line  makes the buyer_id as foreign key.

**You can also try,**

```
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.references :buyer, index: true
      t.references :seller, index: true
      t.references :product, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :transactions, :users, column: :buyer_id
    add_foreign_key :transactions, :users, column: :seller_id
  end
end
```

Comment: But this drops the FKs in the database so you're throwing away referential integrity.

Comment: but it still refer to the `user` to `transaction` relationship and will work as expected. You are talking about the second approach?

Comment: The first one doesn't use a foreign key inside the database so it loses referential integrity, the second one does maintain referential integrity. Sorry, I should have been more explicit.

Comment: I tried the second approach .. it seems to work.. i was able to migrate properly.I created a couple of records and  I was also able to query using User.first.purchases and User.second.sales.

Comment: okay, it seems I missed the forein_key reference in the first approach I added that, I hope the first approach also works. If you find my answer useful, please acceot it.

Comment: @mu is too short, added the reference in first approach too. thankyou for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when ActiveRecord see this:

```
t.references :buyer, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

it tries to create a foreign key inside the database (because `foreign_key: true`) but the naming conventions tell AR that it should be linking to the `buyers` table (because you're referencing `:buyer`).

Just like you specify `class_name:` in your model:

```
belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User'
```

to tell AR not use the conventional `Buyer` name you can override the convention in your migration by modifying your `:foreign_key` option:

```
t.references :buyer, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

to explicitly name the table. Similarly for your other reference that doesn't use the conventional naming scheme:

```
t.references :seller, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mu is too short.. I kind of like this approach also. Is there a way to specify which to_table while using the generate command in the command promt...rails g model Transactions buyer:references ??

Comment: Not that I know of. The generators are meant to cover the common cases, there's nothing wrong with adjusting their output and you should understand what they're generating anyway.